# Flexigrid in zend

Tags: json, zend-framework

i have a page **post2.php** which prints the json array like

```
{
  page: 1,
  total: 239,
  rows: [{
      id: '239',
      cell: ['239', 'ZW', 'ZIMBABWE', 'Zimbabwe', 'ZWE', '716']
    },
    {
      id: '238',
      cell: ['238', 'ZM', 'ZAMBIA', 'Zambia', 'ZMB', '894']
    },
    {
      id: '237',
      cell: ['237', 'YE', 'YEMEN', 'Yemen', 'YEM', '887']
    },
    {
      id: '236',
      cell: ['236', 'EH', 'WESTERN SAHARA', 'Western Sahara', 'ESH', '732']
    },
    {
      id: '235',
      cell: ['235', 'WF', 'WALLIS AND FUTUNA', 'Wallis and Futuna', 'WLF', '876']
    },
    {
      id: '234',
      cell: ['234', 'VI', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.', 'Virgin Islands, U.s.', 'VIR', '850']
    },
    {
      id: '233',
      cell: ['233', 'VG', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH', 'Virgin Islands, British', 'VGB', '92']
    },
    {
      id: '232',
      cell: ['232', 'VN', 'VIET NAM', 'Viet Nam', 'VNM', '704']
    },
    {
      id: '231',
      cell: ['231', 'VE', 'VENEZUELA', 'Venezuela', 'VEN', '862']
    },
    {
      id: '230',
      cell: ['230', 'VU', 'VANUATU', 'Vanuatu', 'VUT', '548']
    }
  ]
}
```

and in zend views i am trying to do like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#flex1").flexigrid({
    url: '/public/**post2.ph**p',
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel: [{
        display: 'ID',
        name: 'id',
        width: 40,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'center'
      },
      {
        display: 'ISO',
        name: 'iso',
        width: 40,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'center'
      },
      {
        display: 'Name',
        name: 'name',
        width: 180,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'left'
      },
      {
        display: 'Printable Name',
        name: 'printable_name',
        width: 120,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'left'
      },
      {
        display: 'ISO3',
        name: 'iso3',
        width: 130,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'left',
        hide: true
      },
      {
        display: 'Number Code',
        name: 'numcode',
        width: 80,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'right'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [{
        name: 'Add',
        bclass: 'add',
        onpress: test
      },
      {
        name: 'Delete',
        bclass: 'delete',
        onpress: test
      },
      {
        separator: true
      },
      {
        name: 'A',
        onpress: sortAlpha
      },
    ],
    searchitems: [{
        display: 'ISO',
        name: 'iso'
      },
      {
        display: 'Name',
        name: 'name',
        isdefault: true
      }
    ],
    sortname: "id"
    sortorder: "asc",
    usepager: true,
    title: 'Countries',
    useRp: true,
    rp: 10,
    showTableToggleBtn: true,
    width: 700,
    height: 255
  });
});
```

this prints the flexigrid layout well.. but never gets the data.it keeps telling processing.
is there some problem in the json array or in the flexigrid calling... or in zend with json.

any suggestions to try out for this problem?

i tried out like this also

```
$.post("/public/server_processing1.php",{},function(data){
alert('hai');
alert(data);
}, "json");
```

and its not even alerting hai ..

full post2.php code is like this

```
<?
error_reporting(1);
function runSQL($rsql) {
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname   = "hms1";
        $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
        $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die ('test');
        return $result;
        mysql_close($connect);
}

function countRec($fname,$tname,$where) {
$sql = "SELECT count($fname) FROM $tname $where";
$result = runSQL($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
return $row[0];
}
}
$page = $_POST['page'];
$rp = $_POST['rp'];
$sortname = $_POST['sortname'];
$sortorder = $_POST['sortorder'];

if (!$sortname) $sortname = 'pa_name';
if (!$sortorder) $sortorder = 'desc';
                if($_POST['query']!=''){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` LIKE '%".$_POST['query']."%' ";
                } else {
                        $where ='';
                }
                if($_POST['letter_pressed']!=''){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` LIKE '".$_POST['letter_pressed']."%' ";
                }
                if($_POST['letter_pressed']=='#'){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' ";
                }
$sort = "ORDER BY $sortname $sortorder";

if (!$page) $page = 1;
if (!$rp) $rp = 10;

$start = (($page-1) * $rp);

$limit = "LIMIT $start, $rp";
$sql = "SELECT pa_id,pa_name,pa_pd_patient_id,pa_name FROM patient_appointment $where $sort $limit";
$result = runSQL($sql);

$total = countRec('pa_id','patient_appointment',$where);

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header("Content-type: text/x-json");
$json = "";
$json .= "{\n";
$json .= "page: $page,\n";
$json .= "total: $total,\n";
$json .= "rows: [";
$rc = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($rc) $json .= ",";
$json .= "\n{";
/*$json .= "cell:['".$row['pa_name']."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['time'])."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['pa_um_id'])."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['pa_pd_patient_id'])."']";*/
$json .= "id:'".$row['pa_id']."',";
$json .= "cell:['".$row['pa_id']."','".$row['pa_name']."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['pa_pd_patient_id'])."']";

$json .= "}";
$rc = true;
}
$json .= "]\n";
$json .= "}";
echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using IE browser. If so IE does not like `<div id="flex1"></div>` container. Change it to `<table id="flex1"></table>` and all should work.